# soda/selenium how to log an assert

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid, soda

I'm sort of new to selenium and soda but love the ability to run selenium with node. So bear with me as I ask a really basic question.

This is a simple login chain I'm running in my script.

```
 browser
    .click('css=a#loginButton')
    .type('css=input.input-medium.email',user)
    .type('css=input.input.pwd',pass)
    .clickAndWait('css=a.btn.login')
    .asserTextPresent('Clients','logged in ok') //client page reached
```

however the message 'logged in ok' is not spitting out anywhere.  I'm certain this is a basic thing I'm missing here but there has to be a way to spit out progress messages as I'm running my test script.  This script has become HUGE, so it's not very easy to track down errors when they occur.  I'd like to sort of log the success as well as the errors.

Comment: Answer: DOH!  It's a function not a string.

For anyone else wondering.  Here's the solution:

browser .click('css=a#loginButton') .type('css=input.input-medium.email',user) .type('css=input.input.pwd',pass) .clickAndWait('css=a.btn.login') .assertTextPresent('Clients',function(){console.log('logged in ok')}) //client page reached

Comment: Apparently I can't have a sudden revelation of the answer and tell you all on this site until 8 hours after I ask the question because I am not a jedi yet.  LOL.

Comment: Perhaps post your solution as an answer and mark it as accepted so others may benefit from your question/answer in the future.

Answer (score 0):

DOH!  It's a function not a string.

For anyone else wondering.  Here's the solution:

```
browser
    .click('css=a#loginButton')
    .type('css=input.input-medium.email',user)
    .type('css=input.input.pwd',pass)
    .clickAndWait('css=a.btn.login')
    .assertTextPresent(
        'Clients',
        function () {
            console.log('logged in ok')
        }); //client page reached
```